# readiness check for google cloud run - how?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I've searched quite extensively in the documentation at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/how-to. I also found the YAML in the console.cloud.google.com, but I can't edit it. Is there a way to set it up using a command I might have missed?

EDIT:
I couldn't find anything in https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/clusters/create about it either.

EDIT2:

I'm looking for a way to make Google cloud run have a readiness check for my app in a container. The same way that kubernetes does it - example here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/. The problem is I don't want to have my service down for 30-60 seconds while the app in the container is still spinning up. Google instantly redirects the traffic causing users to wait for a long time when I push a new build.

EDIT3:
Here's the time it takes to make the first initial request after I've deployed a new version. 
[image: Postman request]

EDIT4:
The app I'm trying to start is in Python. It's a flask app serving a tensorflow model. I needs to load in several files into memory. This takes only 5-10seconds on my computer, but as you can it takes longer on cloud run.

Comment: Can you clarify or expand upon what it is you are asking for or looking for?

Comment: @Kolban See the edit I made :)

Comment: You ask a good question.  I haven't seen anywhere a description of the expectations of what happens when you deploy a new revision.  My guess is that there is no assurance of continuous un-interrupted operation but instead, ALL executions suspend and are queued.

Comment: Some details and data is needed on what you are experiencing. In my experience, I have not seen downtime while provisioning a new version. Traffic continues on the previous revision until the new revision is ready. That is my observation and not a statement of service. If you have data, I will invest the time to investigate/reproduce myself.

Comment: @JohnHanley See the edit I made

Comment: I don't see any data.

Comment: @JohnHanley Maybe look now? Else can you suggest what kind of data you're looking for?

Comment: Now your new edit has a YAML file. I am asking for data on what you experience so that I can test against that. Example, you mention 30-60 seconds. I have never experienced that in months of working on Cloud Run. I don't know why you are worried about the YAML file - that only applies if you want to redeploy on Kubernetes. Also, remember that Cloud Run is not Kubernetes. It is a managed service for containers to simplify deployment. If you are looking for Kubernetes features, deploy on Kubernetes and not Cloud Run.

Comment: @JohnHanley I really appreciate that you are asking questions :) I've made a 4th edit where I show how long time it takes for my app to spin up to server the initial request when a new version is being deployed to cloud run. Is thi the data you're looking for?

Comment: In my experience, Cloud Run from a cold start takes around 400 ms. Your example is 126,305 ms. This is not caused by Cloud Run. Benchmark your app to find out why it takes 126 seconds to respond. UNLESS you are trying to say that a build takes a long time and is holding up your app. The data I am asking for is everything so I can test on my side. After all these comments, I still don't have a clue what you are doing, what the results are and how to reproduce your situation. Note: delete the YAML as it just clutters your question without value.

Comment: How large is the container image, what language and runtime?

Comment: As a side note. You mention readiness. If you want a container to be running at all times, this will be expensive. More so than running the same container on GCE. Cloud Run is not priced for 100% duty cycles. Cloud Run is priced for bursts of traffic that can autoscale to thousands of instances and when there is no traffic, scale down to zero.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm not at my computer atm, but I've added as much information I can. I don't the total size of the image, but the layer I add is close to 100mb.

Comment: I don't need it to be running at all times, I just need it to not have a 126 second down time when deploying a new version :)

Comment: The docker image build isn't the problem - it's the wait time for starting the app :)

Comment: How big are these files that you mention in EDIT 4? I think you are trying to fit an elephant into a shoebox. Cloud Run is for HTTP Request/Response where total time to process is measured in 100 ms increments. The fact that you FINALLY mention TensorFlow and loading files from external sources, tells me you are using the wrong platform.

Comment: @JohnHanley 2x 15ish mb. It's really not that much. And why would it be the wrong platform if I don't need powerful instances and just need to run a model scoring? It works just fine :) (except the startup)

Comment: Also it's not loading files from external sources - it's from part of the container :)

Comment: Okay nevermind I'll find another solution and use kubernetes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cloud Run does not have a readiness check other than confirming your service is listening on the specified port. Once that is done traffic starts routing to the new revision and previous serving revisions are scaled down as they wrap up in-progress requests.

If your goal is to ensure the service is ready ASAP after deployment, you might make a heavier entrypoint that takes care of more setup tasks.

**A "heavier" entrypoint like this will help post-deploy responsiveness, at the cost of slower cold-starts.**

Examples of things you can front-load in the entrypoint (whether in BASH scripts or in your service before turning on the HTTP server):

- Perform all necessary setup tasks such as loading files into memory.
- Establish and preserve in global state any clients or connections to backing services.
- Perform via your service code any healthchecks that backing services and resources are available.
- Warm up in-container caches to minimize the first response.

Again, this optimizes for post-deploy response by penalizing all cold starts.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#optimizing_performance

Answer (score 4):

Note: There's been a recent update and things have improved.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks
"You can configure HTTP and TCP startup health check probes, along with HTTP liveness probes for new and existing Cloud Run services."

Oddly Cloud Run still doesn't allow readiness probes.
But startup and liveness probes are allowed.

The startup probe acts as a readiness probe for initial startup vs an ongoing readiness probe. That being said startup + liveness probe is  probably sufficient in the majority of cases, if it fails it's liveness probe it'll still get removed from load balancing. And startup probe gives replacements enough time to finish booting up before receiving traffic.

---

Note I like to verify things, CloudRun makes it difficult and unintuitive to verify that the startup probe's initialDelaySeconds works as intended & their APIs are annoyingly limited in terms of being automation friendly.

**That being said this will give you an idea of how it works:**

```bash
# Edit Vars
export CR_SERVICE_NAME=startup-probe-test
export PROJECT=chrism-playground
export REGION=us-central1

# Set defaults
gcloud config set project $PROJECT
gcloud config set run/region $REGION

# Deploy a Hello World App for testing purposes
gcloud run deploy $CR_SERVICE_NAME \
--image=us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--max-instances=1

# Hacky Automation to workaround CloudRun's lack of good automation
gcloud run services describe $CR_SERVICE_NAME --format export > example.yaml
export TOP=$(cat example.yaml | grep "        ports:" -B 1000 | grep -v "        ports:")
export BOTTOM=$(cat example.yaml | grep "        ports:" -A 1000)
export MIDDLE=$(echo """
        startupProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
          timeoutSeconds: 2
          periodSeconds: 10
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /healthy
""" | sed '1d')
export REPLACE_NAME=$(echo "$TOP" | grep       "name: $CR_SERVICE_NAME-")
export NEW_TOP=$(echo $TOP | sed s/$REPLACE_NAME/"      name: $CR_SERVICE_NAME-new"/)
echo "$NEW_TOP\n$MIDDLE\n$BOTTOM" | tee updated-example1.yaml

export NEW_TOP=$(echo $TOP | sed s/$REPLACE_NAME/"      name: $CR_SERVICE_NAME-newest"/)
echo "$NEW_TOP\n$MIDDLE\n$BOTTOM" | tee updated-example2.yaml

# Run these (should take about 3 mins for both to finish)
gcloud beta run services replace updated-example1.yaml
gcloud beta run services replace updated-example2.yaml
```

After copy pasting that bash you should see something like this:
[image: Screen Snip of GUI]

Click the symbol near 1 in the image, then check the boxes to see Revision URLs & Actions, and press OK.

Create revision URLs original & startup-probe as shown, then click each to test.

[image: what test looks like]

When I clicked on the original tagged link the site loaded instantly
https://original---startup-probe-test-pxehf3xjcq-uc.a.run.app/

When I clicked on the startup-probe tagged link the site had a loading circle for 60 seconds, and then it worked as expected, which proves the startup probe worked as expected
https://startup-probe---startup-probe-test-pxehf3xjcq-uc.a.run.app/

Answer (score 0):

they recently also added support for liveness and readiness probes in terraform using beta provider.

see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks#terraform_3