# Google Cloud Run Starts Container Before Healthcheck is Healthy

Tags: docker, flask, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

I have an image that has a relatively lengthy startup time of ~5 seconds. In other words, the Flask server is up and running, but I load some data into global variables, so the server is not really operational at this point. If I ping my Google Cloud Run endpoint during this time, the connection will timeout with

```
upstream request timeout
```

To avoid this, I added a docker healthcheck that calls an endpoint in my server. This http request has a timeout of 2 seconds. If it times out, it means that the server is still loading those global files, and the endpoint is not ready to receive requests just yet. This works fine in development, but not in Cloud Run. Cloud Run starts serving traffic to my server before it's done loading - and subsequently, before the container HEALTHCHECK status is actually "healthy".

### My question

How can I delay Cloud Run from delivering traffic to my container until it's fully setup?

### Edit > answer

In my case (using Python + Gunicorn) I was able to solve this using the ["application factory" pattern](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn). That is, start Gunicorn with

```sh
$ gunicorn 'test:create_app()'
```

Where the function `create_app()` returns the Flask application.

My hypothesis as to why this works is because until that function returns, Gunicorn is not yet listening on the port it binds to, and Cloud Run won't start driving traffic to your new running container until that's the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [readiness check for google cloud run - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56348839/readiness-check-for-google-cloud-run-how)

Comment: In the abstract, it does. I thought the HEALTHCHECK in the Dockerfile accounted for that in principle. Concretely, I'm not sure how I can preload stuff in my startup script that will be used by the script managed by Gunicorn, which is what the startup script ultimately runs. Thanks for the info, though. Definitely a step in the right direction.

Comment: Performing lazy initialization of global variables will definetely affect your Cloud Run startup time, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips#performing_lazy_initialization_of_global_variables). Perhaps minimizing the startup time to being as little as possible (the previous documentation shows you several methods) and [adjusting a request timeout](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) may help you in this case.

Comment: Doesn't really solve the problem. I have a couple of large pandas dataframes used as the core of the API. If I load those lazily, the first few requests will still block while those artifacts get initialized. Point is, in Docker land, you could use the health check to account for this. When the container starts, it runs the HEALTHCHECK command, which (using lazy initialization) would not return until the initialization is complete (during which time the container status is not yet healthy). Thus, Cloud Run should wait until the container is healthy before delivering traffic to it.

Answer (score 1):

rodrigo-silveira's solution:

> In my case (using Python + Gunicorn) I was able to solve this using the ["application factory"](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn) pattern. That is, start Gunicorn with
>
> $ gunicorn 'test:create_app()'
>   Where the function create_app() returns the Flask application.
>
> My hypothesis as to why this works is because until that function returns, Gunicorn is not yet listening on the port it binds to, and Cloud Run won't start driving traffic to your new running container until that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Note CloudRun now supports liveness and startup probes.
per https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks

I was very surprised to learn that CR used to not support standard Kubernetes probes, but it seems that after a recent update. Not sure when it happened but at the time of this post (Oct 3, 2022) CloudRun health checks are considered to be in "Preview". Readiness probes still aren't a thing, but startup probes are now allowed so the original cool hack solution can now be replaced by standard startup probes.

Here's a walkthrough of how to implement / test startup probe:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73942357/2548914