# Switching from GKE to Cloud Run - best practices for healthcheck, liveness, readiness and general monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-run

I'm looking towards switching some microservices from GKE to Cloud Run but I'm not able to find out anything related to the healthcheck, liveness, readiness and general monitoring when it goes how it is getting handled when deployed to GKE.

I assume that healthcheck and liveness is possible only when container was deployed to the Cloud Run but it will not be available when service is scaled down to 0. At that time in the monitoring I will get that service is down.

So my question is what are the best practices to handle them for the Cloud Run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will attempt to answer your points one at a time

- Readiness and liveness probes. Cloud Run deploys a LoadBalancer in front of your Service and handles TLS termination for you. Cloud Run expects your container to be available (aka listening on 0.0.0.0 on the defined port) within 4 [minutes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract) of its being deployed, otherwise, it considers it down and tries to restart it.
- Cloud Run has [built-in](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/monitoring) monitoring and alerting if you are using Cloud Ops you don't have to do anything.
- You can ensure your Service will not trigger a false positive by setting the min replicas to 1 ensuring there is always at least 1 replicas of your service available

Let me know if there something you want to clarify

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Regarding keeping 1 replica all the time - is this still will be cost effective compared to have 1 replica of the same deployment in GKE? Let say I have a front-end app which is barely used - I can scale it down to 0 but API behind it  is used by other users/front-ends mostly during the day. So in that case is better to keep always 1 replica as it may be reported as down when no one will use it and scale down to 0?

Comment: Other question - as there no VPC networking how can I prevent accessing that API directly via provided URL but using dedicated API Gateway (NGINX, Kong, Mulesoft, etc) ?

Comment: Cloud Run has a fairly generous free tier [1]. Depending on how much resources your API needs you might not exceed the free tier and keep it on will be cost effective. But if your API backend app is fast to load maybe it's ok to scale it down to 0


[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing

Comment: Regarding your second question, there are many aspects to it.

1 - Cloud Run Services can be made available to the Public (via the Generated URL), Only to the VPC or to the VPC + HTTP LoadBalancer, this is called the Ingress Options [1]
- Cloud Run Service can be accessed from the VPC via something called VPC Serverless Connector [2]

So what you could do for example is deploy the API Gateway on GCE or GKE and it will be able to access your backend

[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress
[2] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access

Comment: To get faster communication between newly deployed service on the Cloud Run and a service on the GKE I assume that I need to have set VPC. Do I need to do the same to communicate faster between two services on the Cloud Run? If so what hostname will befor that secondary service there?

Comment: @boredabdel can you make a slight correction --> startup & liveness probes. Readiness Probes aren't allowed on CR, crazy I know. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73942357/2548914