# Is there a Google Cloud Run startupProbe setting or similar for initial delay

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

I have a docker container that I was attempting to deploy on Google Cloud Run but it takes about 7 minutes to load all the content of a SpringBoot app. When it's deployed using our cluster, we can set a startupProbe to delay the checking and all is good but I was going to try out Cloud Run for our dev site and I keep getting a "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080" error which I believe are due to the fact that it's timing out. I'm able to deploy a version of the same container with just a subset of the data, so I can confirm that it's not actually a PORT issue. I also tried to edit the YAML under the service details to customize the startupProbe but that failed. It seems like Cloud Run has a hard cutoff of about 5 minutes before it fails and I need around 8 minutes, so I'm wondering if there's a way to increase the startupProbe time to something longer? Or do I just have to stick with GKE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot change the Cloud Run health check. Your instance must start responding to HTTP requests within four minutes [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#startup). A request waiting for a container instance to start will be kept in a queue for a maximum of 10 seconds.

Your solution is to redesign your deployment (container) so that is ready to run right away and is not downloading packages/jars, or anything else that takes substantial time. Otherwise, you must select a different service to deploy your application to.

Comment: That's what it looked like but I wanted to make sure. Definitely something that would have been helpful to be able to set manually. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @johnHanley, is there a way if instance service not depends on http request(just pulling events),  mine is failing with `Default STARTUP TCP probe failed 1 time consecutively for container`

Comment: @RaviParekh - I am not sure what you are asking. Cloud Run services must respond to HTTP requests. Create a new post with details and let me know the link.

Answer (score 3):

@akabin per  https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks

As of Oct 3, 2022? CR now supports startup probes in addition to liveness probes. (Still doesn't support readiness probes, at the moment.)

Here's an example of startup probe on CR:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73942357/2548914

Comment: Nice catch! I may be able to swap from using my own GKE clusters to Cloud Run if that's the case. Much cheaper. Thanks!