# How to avoid slow initial response time caused by the SSR function on Firebase with Next.js

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Our React application runs on Firebase. Now we introduces Next.js to improve SEO and initial page load time.
SSR (Server Side Rendering) is done by a Google Cloud Function 2nd gen (Cloud run).

**Issue:** when the SSR function is cold (caused by a deployment, idle, function crash, function restart initiated by Google Cloud), the first request to our apps has to wait around 30 seconds for a response. This is way too much

These 30 seconds contain two phases:

- 2  seconds: Cold start of the Cloud run function (OK, probably nothing can be improved)
- 28 seconds: The Next.js SSR function (Node.js v18) initial start (extract everything, load all modules, things I don't know yet?).

All following requests are very fast as long as the SSR function doesn't restart.

What I tried:

- SSR Cloud function/Cloud run minInstances: 1
  --> issue: Google recycles the instance around every 24 hours. Result: first request is slow again
- SSR Cloud function/Cloud run minInstances: 2
  --> issue: Google recycles the instances around every 24 hours in a short time window one after the other. Users also hit "cold" functions
- [Cloud run HTTP startup probe](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks#healthcheck-endpoint)
  --> here I'm stuck as I don't know how to configure the HTTP startup probe

Reason:

1. How the Firebase deployment is intended:

`firebase experiments:enable webframeworks`

firebase.json

```
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "europe-west1",
      "minInstances": 1,
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "memory": "1GiB",
      "startupProbe": {
        "httpGet": {
          "path": "/health",
          "port": 8080
        },
        "timeoutSeconds": 240,
        "periodSeconds": 240,
        "failureThreshold": 240,
        "initialDelaySeconds": 0
      }
    },
```

`firebase deploy -P dev`

The startupProbe parameters are ignored and not deployed

2. Manually adjust the existing Cloud run function fails due to missing Cloud run function image. Something cleans up the image after the deployment. This solution would be just temporary to test if the http startupProbe would solve my problem.

> Image 'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT/gcf-artifacts/ssrPROJECTdev:version_1' not found.

Comment: Can you please post the edit as an answer? For everyone visibility, so that everyone can see it within the community.

Answer (score 1):

> 2. Manually adjust the existing Cloud run function fails due to missing Cloud run function image. Something*1 cleans up the image after the deployment. This solution would be just temporary to test if the http startupProbe would solve my problem.
>    Image 'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT/gcf-artifacts/ssrPROJECTdev:version_1' not found.
>
> > Image 'europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT/gcf-artifacts/ssrPROJECTdev:version_1' not found.

I found the reason for it. Firebase tools cleans up the images after successful deployment. Disable this step manually:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/src/deploy/functions/release/index.ts#L93
- when locally installed with `npm install -g firebase-tools`: node/v18.15.0/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/index.js:68

Uncomment this line of code and the image is not cleaned up after firebase function deployment:

`await containerCleaner.cleanupBuildImages(haveEndpoints, deletedEndpoints);`

Afterwards I could change the `startupProbe` from default TCP to HTTP in the Google Cloud web GUI [https://console.cloud.google.com/run/deploy/{region}/{functionName}?project={projectName}](https://console.cloud.google.com/run/deploy/%7Bregion%7D/%7BfunctionName%7D?project=%7BprojectName%7D) or with the [gcloud cli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73942357/19547647)

**Still open question**: How to configure the startupProbe directly in the `firebase.json` as documented in the original question.